# getBoundingClientRect return 0 for top, left, right, bottom in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, contenteditable, draftjs

So, I have a contenteditable div powered by Facebook's `draft-js`. I needed to get the visual position of the caret inside that div, and I implemented this (which works in Firefox and Chrome):

```
const selection = window.getSelection && window.getSelection();
if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
    const coordinates = selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
}
```

I get the correct coordinates in case of Chrome and Firefox. However, in Firefox, I am getting 0 for all the position properties. Any workaround/cross-browser solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like I've fixed the issues using next code:

```
let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
range = range.cloneRange();
range.setStart(range.startContainer, 0);
range.getBoundingClientRect();
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmu14hzc/31/).

**UPDATE 13 Feb 2020:**

Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/merksam/wmu14hzc/44/) with fixed caret position for very first line when input is multiline.

Comment: Could you point to where you found this or why it works? I would like to understand why this happens only in Safari.

Comment: @ragurney I don't exactly remember how I found a solution, it was long time ago... And now it seems like it works without my code above. Both in Safari and Chrome.
But I fixed bug for the very first line with multiline text. (caret was below whole input, now it works correct)